# Equivalent alternative to delta-epsilon formulation of limit?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, limits

Is $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$ same as:

> $\forall n \in \mathbb N,
>      \exists \ \varepsilon_n > 0 $ so that:  $$  \ |x_n - L| \leq
>      \varepsilon_n$$ and $$\varepsilon_n \to
>      0, \ \text{when } n \to \infty$$

I know the second assumes and uses the definition of limit again, but my question is if they are equivalent.

Thanks.

Comment: take $\epsilon_n = |x_n-L|*2$.

Comment: @surb, in the regular delta-epsilon formulation for $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = L$, "$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n_\epsilon \in \mathbb N$ so that ...", can $n_\epsilon$ depend on $x_n$?

Answer (score 1):

You can take $\epsilon_n = 2|x_n-L|$, since you assume $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$ for every $\mu > 0$ there exists $N>0$ such that $$|x_n-L|< \mu / 2 \qquad \forall n \geq N $$ and so we 
  have 
$$|\epsilon_n| = 2|x_n-L|< \mu \qquad \forall n \geq N$$
this shows that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \epsilon_n = 0$.

Comment: Thanks. So you have shown that the regular definition implies the alternative. How about the other direction?

Comment: @Tim Let $(\epsilon_k) \subset \mathbb R$ a sequence such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \epsilon_k = 0$ then for every $k$ there exists $n_k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|x_{n_k}-L|<\epsilon_k$ (where we use the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L$ )the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $L$ and satisfy the property.

Comment: $n_k$ really exists because for every $\mu$ ( $= \epsilon_k$) there exists $N>0$ such that $|x_l-L|<\mu$ for every $l > N$ and then you choose $n_k = N+1$

Comment: (1) "the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $L$", but $\epsilon_k$ isn't arbitrary. (2) I am still not sure if you have shown $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = L$

Comment: @Tim Ahh sorry I missunderstood the question, so if $\lim_{k \to \infty} \epsilon_k = 0 $ and $|x_k-L|\leq \epsilon_k $ for every $k$ then let $\mu > 0$, there exists some $N>0$ such that $|\epsilon_k|< \mu$ for every $k > N$. In particular $|x_k-L|\leq \epsilon_k < \mu$ for every $k > N$. and so $\lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = L$

Answer (score 1):

The better way to formulate something like your description is to first rewrite the definition of the limit as

$$(\exists \delta : \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+)(\forall \varepsilon > 0,x \in \mathbb{R}) \, |x-c|<\delta(\varepsilon,x) \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon.$$

The function whose existence is implied by this statement is called the *modulus of convergence*. Now suppose $\delta_1$ is a modulus of convergence and $\delta_2 \leq \delta_1$. Then $\delta_2$ is also a modulus of convergence.

Therefore we can assume that the modulus of convergence is strictly increasing and continuous, by taking an arbitrary modulus of convergence and decreasing it. This means the modulus of convergence has a continuous inverse, which I will call $\varepsilon : \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+$.

What we have said is just:

$$(\exists \varepsilon : \mathbb{R}_+ \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_+)(\forall \delta > 0,x \in \mathbb{R}) \, |x-c|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon(\delta,x).$$

But the original statement also implies that

$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R}) \, \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \varepsilon(\delta,x) = 0$$

because $\varepsilon(\delta,x)$ is the inverse of $\delta(\varepsilon,x)$ which has the same property.

Everything here should go through just fine in the opposite direction: if we assume $\lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \varepsilon(\delta,x) = 0$ then we can invert it (by *increasing* it if necessary) to get a function $\delta$ defined for arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$, which is what is required for convergence.

Comment: Thanks. More generally, how about the convergence in a topology? Can it have similar alternative? Let $f$ be a mapping between two topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. $\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = y$ is defined as for any open set $U_y$ containing $y$, there exists an open set $V_x$ containing $x$, so that $f(V_x) \subseteq U_y$.

Comment: I don't think so. Everything goes through fine for maps between metric spaces, but in a topological space it is not clear what the analogue of $(\forall x \in X) \, \lim_{\delta \to 0^+} \varepsilon(\delta,x)$ is, when $\varepsilon(\delta,x)$ is a neighborhood system.

Comment: Would you like to see me post it as a separate question?

Comment: @Tim that's probably better. I still don't think it will work, because in a topological space the "$\varepsilon$" is not of the same type as the "$\delta$".

Answer (score 0):

I can't make sense of the  "as ...  tends to infinity/zero"  parts of your formulation.  The great thing about the definition of limits is, that they are totally finitary. No infinity is involved.

So my answer is: No the definitions do not make sense.

Comment: "As" means "when". I dont' create the alternative definition. I saw it by someone else, and don't know if it is a mistake. Would you think it twice?